# Popup menu: Set a selected item on creation

Tags: popup-menu

I have a `popup_menu`. I want to have the second, for example, option chosen when it opens, rather than the first.

Is this possible? I've looked in various threads on the internet and `:help popup` and found nothing. But I thought it would be worthwhile to ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the popup creation functions return a window ID. So save the return value of `popup_menu`...

```
    let popid = popup_menu(...)
```

Then use that to reach into the popup buffer and move the cursor...

```
    call win_execute(popid, 'call cursor(2, 1)')
```

[`win_execute()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#win_execute()) is like `execute()` but operates in the context of a specified window.

This is mentioned at the end of [`:h popup-buffer`](https://vimhelp.org/popup.txt.html#popup-buffer).